# No matching method error when adding 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

I have the following method:

```
function Q(penalties::Array{Float64, 1}, Q::Array{Float64, 2})
    Q_ar = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, N+1, N+1)
    for r in 1:N+1
        Q_ar = Q_ar + penalties[r] * Q[r]
    end
    return Q_ar
end
```

That I'm calling, but I'm getting the following error:

```
(base.oneto(16), base.oneto(16))
error: loaderror: methoderror: no method matching +(::array{float64,2}, ::float64)
for element-wise addition, use broadcasting with dot syntax: array .+ scalar
closest candidates are:
  +(::any, ::any, !matched::any, !matched::any...) at operators.jl:538
  +(!matched::complex{bool}, ::real) at complex.jl:301
  +(!matched::missing, ::number) at missing.jl:115
  ...
stacktrace:
 [1] q(::array{float64,1}, ::array{float64,2}) at /users/prikshetsharma/documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/trajectory.jl:42
 [2] top-level scope at /users/prikshetsharma/documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/trajectory.jl:50
 [3] include(::function, ::module, ::string) at ./base.jl:380
 [4] include(::module, ::string) at ./base.jl:368
 [5] exec_options(::base.jloptions) at ./client.jl:296
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:506
in expression starting at /users/prikshetsharma/documents/clotorch/src/clotorch/flight/trajectory.jl:50
```

How to fix this error? The error is occurring at the line:

```
Q_ar = Q_ar + penalties[r] * Q[r]
```

My intention is to add all the

```
penalties[r] * Q[r]
```

together, and return the result with the array Q_ar.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you use penalties[r] it returns the r(th) element of penalties which in this case is of the type float64, not an array

Comment: you want an array with products of the corresponding elements of penalties and Q, and you want to add it to Q_ar, correct?

Comment: Also note it won't necessarily cause a problem but using the same name for your function and one of the inputs (both are called `Q`) is very confusing and could lead to hard-to-detect bugs down the track.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are preallocating memory without initialization. So instead of `Q_ar = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, N+1, N+1)` you need to write `Q_ar = zeros(N+1, N+1)` so that further addition to elements of `Q_ar` makes sense.

Then you are trying to add some number to the whole array. In Julia you can add number to number, array to array if their dimensions matches, but if you want to add a number to every element of an array you should use the broadcasting `1 .+ [1,2,3]` instead of `1 + [1,2,3]` which produces method error.

After that you're using strange global `N` which can cause some errors and type-instability. It is better to get size inside of a function `n = length(penalties)`

Finally your code will look like

```
function Q(penalties::Array{Float64, 1}, Q::Array{Float64, 2})
    n = length(penalties)
    Q_ar = zeros(n, n)
    for r in 1:n
        Q_ar .+= penalties[r] * Q[r]
    end
    Q_ar
end
```

But there are several questions to the sense of this code. You are making a matrix with similar elements, so why don't use `fill(penalties ⋅ Q[:,1], (n, n))` because this part

```
    for r in 1:n
        Q_ar .+= penalties[r] * Q[r]
    end
```

is just computing inner product of `penalties` and `Q[:,1]`